# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

Tags: swift

I want to use mutating functions for objects declared in extension. And really want to make its chaining with functions.
I have no idea how to fix this.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var value: Int { get set }
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    mutating func mutatingMethod(_ newValue: Int) -> Self {
        value = newValue
        return self
    }
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    var value: Int = 0
    
    func otherMethod() {
        
    }
}

// Error: 
// Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 
// function call returns immutable value
var someObj = SomeClass().mutatingMethod(3)

someObj.otherMethod()
```

Comment: This only works for classes, so you’d need to make your protocol into a class-bound protocol (`protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep `SomeProtocol` available to be adopted by `structs` and/or don't want to change your declarations, the error can be avoided just by the way you make calls. For example, this works:

```swift
var someObj = SomeClass()
someObj = someObj.mutatingMethod(3)
someObj.otherMethod()
```

The reason is that `mutating` members can only be called on `var` declarations. Though, in your call chain the result of `SomeClass()` is not assigned anywhere and Swift compiler treats it as if it was `let`.

For example, it won't work also if you call it like this:

```swift
let someObj = SomeClass() // The only difference is let.
someObj = someObj.mutatingMethod(3)
someObj.otherMethod()
```

The error is the same, but worded more obviously: `cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'someObj' is a 'let' constant`.

Comment: Superb, this one is correct answer and answer has detailed.